# Show GSP in Grails 3 rest-api profile

Tags: grails

I added `compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp"` to a grails 3 project created under rest-api profile so I could return an HTML view with the API documentation. I created the index.gsp file, made the war, run the app and got this error

```
ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/catalog] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

I assume that the error is that the gsp was not compiled, because on the console when I run `gradle war` I see

```
:processResources
:classes
:compileGsonViews
:war
```

Is that the error? Can I add somehow the compile gsp task to the war task?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems that adding `apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"` to `build.gradle` file (apart from adding the dependency) does the trick.

Comment: I fought this for hours. I needed to add some json views to an existing web template application, and everything was working fine locally in both grails dev mode and command line -jar mode. However, the second it was deployed to a remote linux box, all the gson/json views couldn't be resolved.

Adding the apply plugin statement (which was missing from my build.gradle because of the template I created the app with originally) fixed the issue the first try. Thanks!